# Visual Studio 2017 shows IntelliSense errors on unreal engine 4 projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I working on a unreal engine 4.20 project, I compile my project successfully, but show many IntelliSense errors.

I searched in the google and stackoverflow. I deleted .vs folder .suo file and unload/load the project. also I installed Windows Universal CRT SDK and Windows 8.1 SDK/Windows 10 SDK but still have problem.

Even I create new first person unreal engine project, It show me huge IntelliSense errors while i can compile project without any errors.

What is problem? how can fix that?

Errors sample is here:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, show the error text example

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov I edited my question and add errors sample

Comment: How are you building exactly? I.e. have you downloaded and built the source from github, or downloaded the engine from epic s site, and what is your build configuration? Also, how are you creating the visual studio project?

Answer (score 2):

In epic's docs it's mentioned that intellisense could detect false errors because the intellisense system is too slow to scan all the files of the project and the engine. The solution suggested in the docs is to hide the intellisense errors and to only inspect the errors which are displayed by the compiler output. You can do this by setting the dropdown to `Build`.

For more information visit https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/VisualStudioSetup/